# Spring Security JWT Auth for Multiple UserDetailsService implementations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a web application with 2 domains (User and Employee), these domains have different fields.

I'm looking for a way to be able to authenticate against both Users and Employees using Spring security.

I can currently authenticate with a User and get back a valid JWT. Would I need to create another class extending UserDetailsService for the Employee? Would I have a second constructor in my class that extends UserDetails to create an Employee? How would I handle the UserDetailsService in my Config class to cater for both ?

This is what I have atm:

**MyUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;



    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String emailAddress) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid credentials / Account not found");
        }
        return MyUserDetails.createAppUser(user);
    }


}
```

**MyUserDetails**

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

        private User user;
        private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

        public MyUserDetails(User user, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            this.user = user;
            this.authorities = authorities;
        }
        
        public static MyUserDetails createAppUser(User user) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return new MyUserDetails(user, authorities);
        }


        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return authorities;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return user.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return user.getEmailAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**JWT Filter**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtServiceImpl jwtService;
    private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = jwtService.getToken(request) ;

        if (token!=null && jwtService.validateToken(token)) {

            String email = jwtService.extractUserName(token);
            Claims claims = jwtService.extractAllClaims(token);


            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername() ,null , userDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${spring.security.ant.matchers}")
    private String[] securityAntMatchers;

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter authFilter;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(securityAntMatchers).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors().disable()
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
    @Embedded
    private Name name;

    private LocalDate dateJoined;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<ContactDetail> contactDetails = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    private String emailAddress;
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_number")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int employeeNumber;
    @Embedded
    private Name name;
    private LocalDateTime dateJoined;
    @NotBlank(message = "Required")
    private String password;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<ContactDetail> contactDetails = new HashSet<>();

    private String emailAddress;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Comment: @dur I did try it, I also left some comments on one of the possible solutions but waiting to see if the guy gets back to me.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better for you to have a base user that Spring Security and the UserDetailsService uses, and then create a user and employee role (Granted Authority).

You would then have one base user object, which your "User" and "Employee" types can extend. The base user object would be the one that you have implementing the UserDetails interface.

Comment: Basically, I use BaseEnity inlcude id, name, email, password, and List<Role>.After that, I declare Employee, User extends BaseEntity.

Comment: Now, I don't care about the different between User, Employee, just add dummy field on these entites

Comment: you are aware that handing out JWTs directly to browsers is a security risk, that is why there is no such code in spring security, and why you have to write all this custom code. For instance how would you logout a user with this setup?

Comment: @Toerktumlare, if the OP is interested in the security aspect of this, they can read: https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/

Comment: i just think that answering and helping ppl that are clearly building insecure authentication is not the way to go.

Comment: I think that while you have a valid point, the point of asking a question here at SO is so people can get an answer to their question, not best practices. 

I do think that answering a question (or attempting to), while also stating why something shouldn't be done a certain way is better than just saying this is insecure and not answering the original question.

Just so you know, I do think that you have a valid point.

Comment: @SpeedyTheSnail, can you help me by a simple demo?